# Is a conditional LPR/Greencard classed as National ID card for travel?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, identity-cards

I want to know how best to answer the ESTA question:

> Have you ever been issued a passport or national identity card for travel by another country?

Different sites I read say different things regarding a permanent and
conditional LPR Card classifications. So I am a little confused.

I once had a conditional LPR/Greencard. It expired after I left the USA over 2 years ago and I did not renew it. So is a conditional LPR/greencard classed as national ID for travel?

edited: corrected terminology of 'temporary' LPR to 'conditional' LPR where applicable.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that this is intended to cover citizens' IDs like those issued by some EU countries, so you don't  need to enter your old green card.  But it won't hurt anything if you do.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, I just need to be clear because I want to make sure if I am not providing my expired GC number in answer to this ESTA question I am indeed doing the right thing under the requirements for this question. So to confirm: a conditional LPR/Greencard is NOT considered to be a 'National ID card for travel', is that correct?

Comment: Or the passport cards issued by Ireland and possibly a few other countries by now. (These are ICAO compliant travel documents, unlike the US "passport card".)

Comment: @MichaelHampton in what way is the US passport card not ICAO compliant?

Comment: @phoog Only the machine readable area on the back and the physical dimensions of the card make any pretense at following ICAO specifications. The front has a completely different layout, for instance. And the State Department has [explicitly said](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/34455/1434) that they are not intending to produce an ICAO compliant card.