# Is an ESTA likely to be denied if I have had a previous Temporary LPR/ Greencard that is now expired?

Tags: transit-visas, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I'm an Australian Citizen and need to travel to enter the USA for 3 days en route to another country. I have had an ESTA for traveling to USA in the past (previous to my conditional LPR) and have never been denied any travel visa anywhere in the world and I travel frequently. However, my temporary/conditional LPR/green card expired after I left the USA over 2 years ago, and I have not returned since or renewed it -- I could not do so anyway, due to not meeting the conditions to be able to keep it current (living outside USA for more than 2 years).

I'm concerned. Is that likely to hinder the approval of a new ESTA application so I can travel through the USA for a few days?

In the ESTA question "Do you have a passport or national ID for travel by any other country? Whats does it mean by 'any other country'? Is that any other country other than USA or does it include the USA?

And was my conditional LPR/green card ever classed as a National ID issued for TRAVEL by any other country?

Comment: were you able to get your ESTA approved after filing i407? I have the same situation as you did. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Because the ESTA application question appears just after the applicant has entered their passport info — which passport must be from other than the US — the phrase "any other country" means *any country other than the country which issued the applicant's passport*.

Unless someone weighs in on having had this exact experience, no one can guess if you'll be granted ESTA status or not. And even if someone has had that experience, there may be some difference in personal circumstances or travel history such that their "I got ESTA" might not apply to you.

Your second question about a Green Card being seen as a "National ID" was answered by @phoog earlier [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/148167/is-a-temporary-lpr-greencard-classed-as-national-id-card-for-travel).

Comment: Thanks @David. It certainly makes better sense now. I wanted to make sure I do things the correct way to avoid any complications. I am still a little unclear if there was anything else I should know or I am required to do following the expiry of my conditional LPR before applying for an ESTA? There has never been any problems or issues surrounding my old LPR other than I left the USA when it was valid and did not return and it expired before I could remove the conditional part. Based on that would you have any further insight whether that is likely to hinder my ESTA application to the USA?

Comment: @David I always assumed "any other country" meant any other apart from the country of your citizenship.

Comment: @kiradotee you are correct.  The question "have you been issued a passport [etc.] by any other country" follows immediately after the applicant enters the details of the passport being used in the ESTA application.  It is therefore a natural conclusion that "other country" means any country other than the one that issued that passport (which will include other country or countries of citizenship for people with multiple citizenships).  In fact, for a former US citizen, the phrase "any other country" would indeed *include* the US.

Comment: @phoog Based on that then is an expired temporary LPR or greencard actually classified as a National ID issued 'for travel'? From your answer on a previous thread it would suggest that it is not. So I am still not sure whether it is crucial to put in my expired LPR number in this instance? And if I do or do not, how it might effect my ESTA applicaton?

Comment: @Lilly a "national ID" is generally a non-passport document issued to a citizen of the country issuing the ID.  So no, a green card is not a "national ID" in that sense.  But like I said in my answer to your other question, it won't hurt anything if you mention it.  I don't think your decision to mention or not mention your green card in response to this question will have much impact on the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, all. I'll amend the Answer.

Comment: Thanks all! @phoog and David -That has really helped clarify some things.:)  You all seem quite knowledgeable on some of these topics - I have since read elsewhere on this forum that if an LPR no longer intends to maintain their LPR status an i407 Notice of Intention to Abandon LPR status may be required to be filed before applying for any other entry permit. Is that likely to apply here with my temporary LPR/Greencard that has long since expired? And does that even need to happen before I apply for an ESTA? Or would it be better to start a new question thread for that ?

Comment: @Lilly Because Stack Exchange aims at being a question-answer site, and not a discussion one, I'd suggest you start a new question.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I don't quite understand your answer -- what leads you to believe the ESTA could be denied?  Having multiple passports/IDs is not a blocker for ESTA, I've had several granted myself.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I did not say that folks with multiple passports won't get ESTA; your experience shows clearly that multiple passports alone are not necessarily disqualifying. My point was that given the vagaries of ESTA administration, factors other than multiple passports (which I called "personal circumstances or travel history") _might_ lead to ESTA denial.